# Как подключить Android приложение к удалённой БД?

Tags: android, sql, база-данных

Пишу приложение в Android Studio. И возникла проблема, не знаю как подключить приложение к удаленной базе данных, мне нужно к примеру авторизовать пользователя, информация о котором лежит в БД. Как мне вообще создать и подключить БД к приложению?

Comment: Что это за БД, где она находится, через что организован доступ к ней?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в том то и дело, что её еще не существует. Я и хочу узнать, можно ли к ней как то подобраться через андроид? Допустим я создам mySQL бд. Как мне к ней пробраться?

Comment: Не пишите важную информацию в комментариях! Всё необходимое должно содержаться в вопросе! Отредактируйте его.

Comment: Это долго и сложно, если делать правильно и беспокоиться о сохранности данных. Краткое описание: поднимаете сервак, например аренда VPS у хостера. Разбираетесь с Linux. Ставите СУБД. В ней создаёте БД, таблицы. Оборачиваете все запросы к БД в API, чтобы к БД не было доступа всему интернету и общение шло через JSON. Для этого, например, можно Spring взять. За месяц-два его вполне можно освоить на достуточном для задачи уровне. После этого с андроида просто шлите HTTP запросы на свой сервер на Spring, а он будет преобразованную из БД инфу на андроид в виде JSON выдавать.